# What exactly is the Python Command Line for?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python so this is a probably a stupid question. I'm fairly familiar with Java and I mostly use Emacs to write code and compile them using Window cmd. So I'm confused what the Python command line is for.
I think that's what it's called but I'm not sure. It looks similar to the cmd because of the black background and white texts (but with `>>>` instead of, for example, `C:\Users\Owner>`)

What is it for? I know I can run a python file on cmd using the `py` command, such as `C:\Users\Owner> py hello.py`
but what is the python command line for?

I understand that I can run python code by entering code directly into the python command line. For example:

```py
>>> print("hello")
```

but I'm wondering why this is useful if you can just create a file using, for example, emacs and compile it using the cmd.

Thank you to anyone who replies!

TLDR: What is the Python command line for and why wouldn't I just use the cmd to compile files.

Comment: its a fun, tIts a fun playground, but essentially, passing in a file to python really much runs the interpretor, but in a semi-headless fashion.

Comment: It's a REPL, which is generally used for quick code experiments